# A Curious (definitely wrong) result of Absolute Entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, entropy, ideal-gas

The Gibbs free energy is defined as

$$G=H-TS$$

Differentiating both sides

$$dG=dH-TdS-SdT$$

For an adiabatic reversible expansion of an **ideal gas**, we would have $dG=0$, and $dS=0$.

Thus we can write, $dH=SdT$

Also, $dH=n C_p dT$.

Finally I reach the strange result that $S=nC_p$. How can I define absolute entropy so simply. Something is definitely very wrong here. Please correct me.

Comment: Integrate dT and add constant.

Comment: Double check your equations and assumptions. For instance for which kind of process can you assume dG=0? What happens to the temperature during an adiabatic reversible expansion of an ideal gas?

Comment: I am assuming dG=0 based on the fact that it is a reversible process and dG=0 in a reversible process. Does this not hold always?

Comment: No, for instance $dG \neq 0$  for a reversible isothermal expansion.

Comment: Ok.., how can I prove that dG≠0 in reversible isothermal expansion of an ideal gas?

Comment: BTW stumbled on this related post:  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131179/is-constant-pressure-heat-capacity-entropy-during-adiabatic-reversible-expansi

Comment: So is dG≠0 in reversible expansion of ideal gas as well??...as is written in the answer of that post.

Answer (score 2):

The Gibbs free energy change is zero in the case of reversible processes carried out at constant temperature and pressure, but that isn't the case if these conditions are not observed.

As a demonstration consider an isothermal *reversible* expansion of an ideal gas.

Since the temperature is constant, the free energy change is given by

$$\Delta G = \Delta H - T \Delta S$$

Because the gas is ideal and T constant, $\Delta U = 0$, and from the second law of thermodynamics it follows that

$$\Delta S = \frac{q_\text{rev}}{T}= -\frac{w_\text{rev}}{T} = \frac{\int_{V_1}^{V_2}p dV}{T} = \frac{\int_{V_1}^{V_2} \frac{nRT}{V} dV}{T} = nR\log \left( \frac{V_2}{V_1} \right)$$

It also follows that

$$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta (pV) = 0 + \Delta (nRT) = RT \Delta n = 0$$

since the system is closed.

But then

$$\Delta G = - nRT\log \left( \frac{V_2}{V_1} \right) \neq 0$$

The free energy change is not zero because the pressure changed during the process.

For the reversible adiabatic expansion of an ideal gas

$$\begin{align}  \Delta S &= 0  \\ \Delta H &= \int_{T_1}^{T_2} C_p dT  = C_p \Delta T \\ \Delta G &= \int_{P_1}^{P_2} V dP - \int_{T_1}^{T_2} S dT =  (V_1P_1^{C_V/C_P})\left(\frac{C_P}{C_P-C_V}\right)( P_2^{1-C_V/C_P}-P_1^{1-C_V/C_P}) - S\Delta T  \end{align}$$

The integral over P in the expression for $\Delta G$ can be evaluated after substituting the following expression for the volume in terms of pressure:

$$V=(V_1P_1^{C_V/C_P}) P^{-C_V/C_P}$$